# Log in to Community as User - Auditing

Tags: community, login

As a System Administrator, if I use the 'Log in to Community as User' functionality from a Contact record to access the Community:

[image: log in to Community]

Is there any way of knowing who that system administrator user is during the time they are logged in as another user? For example, users are able to create a record through the Community and I would want to know that Billy Bob (the contact/community user) is the creator/owner and that John Doe is the system admin who is logged in as Billy Bob (and be able to set John Doe in a user lookup field during the record creation process).

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no direct way to achieve this, however you can build your custom solution. In Winter 16 - `SetupAuditTrail`  is available as an Object and we can use SOQL against it. It's same data, we were accessing it using "View Setup Audit Trail" menu from setup.

Sample SOQL -

```
SELECT Action,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Display,Id,Section 
FROM SetupAuditTrail Order by CreatedDate DESC
```

we can add condition for Section = 'Manage Users' in SOQL query. You might want to play with it using workbench or Developer console.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that enhancement. I'll dig into this a little further. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I looked into this and it doesn't appear you are able to query for the user that is being logged in as. Both CreatedBy and DelegateUser (although I don't know that this field is working correctly) appear to return the admin performing the action.